# Conditional style class on h:body tag

Tags: css, jsf-2

I need to be able to change the styleClass of my h:body tag based on the version of Internet Explorer. Can anyone tell me how to do this without using OmniFaces?

Thanks in advance

/Søren

Answer (score 0):

You could put your version-specific styles in separate files and then use IE's conditional markup.  For example:

```
<!--[if gte IE 8]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="ie8.css"/>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: yes - but our design agency would like to avoid having multiple css files. This was also my proposal for them :-)